# agregar JavaScript a una pagina en drupal 7

Tags: javascript, script, drupal7

tengo un problema, tengo que agregar un script a una pagina en drupal 7 , pero al agregar el script en el contenido de la pagina este no se guarda, como agrego un javascript a una pagina de drupal 7 ? gracias de ante mano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto imagen de como agregue el script.

Answer (score 0):

En el formato selecciona "FULL HTML", o puedes instalar este modulo de Drupal javascript_libraries

https://www.drupal.org/project/javascript_libraries

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un archivo.js con el contenido de tu script y luego agregarlo asi:

```
drupal_add_js('archivo.js');
```